# Passing a PHP variable to a javascript on an ONCHANGE event

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I want to change the text of a label when i choose a new value in a dropdown list.

These are my php arrays:

```
$data = array(
              '1'=>array('country'=>'Philippines','capital'=>'Manila'),
              '2'=>array('country'=>'Finland','capital'=>'Helsinki'),
              '3'=>array('country'=>'India','capital'=>'Delhi') 
            );

$countries = array(1=>'Philippines', 2=>'Finland', 3=>'India');
```

This is how it should be displayed in the page:

```
    <div><?php echo form_label('Country: ', 'country'); ?></div>
    <div><?php echo form_dropdown('country',$countries,'',
                      'onChange="javascript:displayCapitalCity(?????)"'); ?></div>

    <div><?php echo form_label('Capital: ', 'capitalLabel'); ?></div>
    <div id="capcity"><?php echo form_label('','capitalcity'); ?></div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
function displayCapitalCity(?????){
document.getElementById('capcity').innerHTML = '??????';
}
```

**?????** should be the capital city of chosen country. How will I pass the value of $data[*index of chosen country*]['capital']?

Comment: how does the generated markup looks like

Comment: This might be a silly question, but why not create the capital city array in JavaScript in the first place? It would save you a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<div><?php echo form_dropdown('country',$countries,'',
                      'onChange="javascript:displayCapitalCity(this)"'); ?></div>


var jsdata = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
function displayCapitalCity(_targ){
   document.getElementById('capcity').innerHTML = jsdata[_targ.value]['capital'];
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. But how will i get the value for $res[_targ.value]['capital'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Best way (in my opinion) is to translate the PHP $data array into JSON, making it accessible on the client side (i.e. JavaScript).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php printf('var countriesData = %s;', json_encode($data)) ?>
function displayCapitalCity(index) {
    document.getElementById('capcity').innerHTML = countriesData[index].capital;
}
</script>
```

Just make sure you're passing for correct index corresponding with the $data array.

Assuming you are using CodeIgniter, the onChange should look like that:

```
onchange="javascript:displayCapitalCity(this.value)"
```